# How can I copy application settings from one user account to the other on the same machine?

Tags: mouse, user-account, settings

I have two user accounts (a work and personal account) on my MacBook Pro 5,3 with OS X 10.11.6.
On both I use the same Logitech MX Master mouse in combination with the Logitech Options application.
I would like to keep the settings (scroll speed, pointer speed, etc...) in sync such that I do not have to do the setup on each account.

How can I copy settings stored by an application (Logitech Options in this case) on one account to the other?

#### Attempts

I have looked in `~/Library/Application Support/Logitech/Options`. There I find 4 `.xml` files. However, changing a setting in Logitech Options does not change the Date Modified of these files. Hence I think these files do not store the settings.

I have also run `lsof | grep -i logitech` when Logitech Options is open. Unfortunately I only find files in my user directory related to the saved state of the application (`~Library/Saved Application State/com.logitech.Logi-Options.savedState/`). My understanding is that these relate to the window state of the application, not to the settings stored by it.

Comment: Have you looked for an appropriate `.plist` file in `~/Library/Preferences` that might belong to Logitech?

Comment: I did not. But that seems to be the answer. I found a file `com.logitech.manager.setting.0006b017.plist` which changed its modification date after I changed the settings. Make it an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most, but not all, applications save some settings in a `.plist` file in `~/Library/Preferences`.

Look for and appropriately named file containing the name of the application in question.

Copy this file to the same location under a different User's Home folder.

Note that you may have to adjust permissions on the file for the other User Account to read/write to the file.

Answer (score 4):

You can backup your settings using Logi Options app and restore them from another computer.

1. Log in or create your Logitech account
2. Select your device -> "MORE"
3. Choose "Backups" menu
4. Press "CREATE BACKUP NOW"

After that you can restore settings on another computer from the same menu.

Notice that settings are being restored for the selected device only; so e.g. if you have Logitech mouse and keyboard, you have to do this procedure for each of them.